# Nosetests assert_equal apparently not equal to python ==

Tags: python, unit-testing, dictionary, nose

I'm programming the temperature control for a setup that has different sources (in this example only one):

```
source = Source()

sources_dict = {
    key: source
}

temp_control = TempControl(args) #A dictionary is built on instantiation based on args
                                 #and assigned to temp_control.sources
```

sources_dict is defined with the same args of TempControl(args). See the content of the for loop for what works and does not.

```
for key, value in tempControl.sources.iteritems():
    assert_equal(value, sources_dict[key]) #Fails
    tempControl.sources[key] == sources_dict[key] #Works
    value == sources_dict[key] #Works
```

When it does not, I get the following error message:

```
AssertionError: <pvd_temp_control.Source object at 0x02AA63B0> !=   <pvd_temp_cont
rol.Source object at 0x02AA6330>
-------------------- >> begin captured stdout << ---------------------
sources_dict: {'Cu': <pvd_temp_control.Source object at 0x02AA6330>}
tempControl.sources: {'Cu': <pvd_temp_control.Source object at 0x02AA63B0>}
source: <pvd_temp_control.Source object at 0x02AA6330>
--------------------- >> end captured stdout << ----------------------
```

Any ideas why?

Comment: How do you know `value == sources_dict[key]` returns True? The code you show just computes a throwaway Boolean value.

Comment: The value `sources_dict['Cu']` is at location **0x02AA6330**, which is different from `tempControl.sources['C'`]`, which is at **0x02AA63B0**. They are different objects of the same class.

Comment: Does this pass? `assert tempControl.sources[key] == sources_dict[key]` I suspect that it will fail, simply because they are two different objects.

Comment: It is false, but I am wondering why. I just want to see that the dictionaries have the same keys and values, not that they are the same object. Thats why I don't insert the complete dictionaries into an assert_equal statement

Answer (score 1):

I had to be more specific. assert_equal won't do magic and go through the dictionary. This is correct for example:

```
for key, value in tempControl.sources.iteritems():
    assert_equal(value.element_name, sources_dict[key].key_name)
```